# Get the index for the last 1 for each row in a data table (R)

Tags: r, data.table

I'm currently trying to get used to `data.table` package in `R`. I want to get the index for the last `1` ocurring in each row of a data table, say `a` and add that new column to `a`. My code for this is the following:

```
  a = data.table(matrix(sample(c(0,1),500,rep=T),50,10))
  a[,ind:=apply(a==1,1,function(x) max(which(x)))]
```

Nevertheless, I think this can be written in a short way using more `data.table` syntax. Therefore, my question is: how to do this without the `apply` function within the `j` component of `[`?

Comment: `a[, ind := max.col(.SD==1, "last")]` should probably be faster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question. Yes, the `apply` by row isn't page efficient, the `which` will be allocating for each and every row, and the `a==1` creates a new logical matrix as large as `a`.

In `data.table` we do things by column.  *Sometimes*, it's `data.table`-ish to use a `for` loop through columns (never `for` loop through rows) :

```
a[,ans:=0L]
for (i in 1:10) set(a,which(a[[i]]==1),"ans",i)

identical(a$ind, a$ans)
# [1] TRUE
```

As you can see it's a completely different style.  But, I think, this should be :

- page efficient; i.e., it runs by columns which are contiguous in memory
- needs working memory as large as (just) one column rather than whole of `a`
- calls `which()` (a non primitive, vectorized function) `10` rather than `nrow(a)` times

I didn't do any speed tests, though, so I might have to eat my words.

See `?set`.

In response to comment, to inspect how it works, `set` happens to return a pointer to the `data.table`, so we can look at the first few rows as it progresses.

```
a[,ans:=0L]   # add column by reference, initialized with 0L

> head(a)
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 ans
1:  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  1   1   0
2:  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  1   1   0
3:  0  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  1   0   0
4:  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  1  1   1   0
5:  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0   1   0
6:  1  1  0  1  1  0  1  0  1   1   0
```

Now hopefully the following reveals how it's working :

```
> for (i in 1:10) print(head(set(a,which(a[[i]]==1),"ans",i)))
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 ans
1:  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  1   1   0
2:  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  1   1   0
3:  0  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  1   0   0
4:  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  1  1   1   0
5:  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0   1   1
6:  1  1  0  1  1  0  1  0  1   1   1
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 ans
1:  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  1   1   0
2:  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  1   1   0
3:  0  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  1   0   2
4:  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  1  1   1   0
5:  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0   1   2
6:  1  1  0  1  1  0  1  0  1   1   2
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 ans
1:  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  1   1   3
2:  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  1   1   3
3:  0  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  1   0   2
4:  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  1  1   1   0
5:  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0   1   3
6:  1  1  0  1  1  0  1  0  1   1   2
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 ans
1:  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  1   1   3
2:  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  1   1   4
3:  0  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  1   0   2
4:  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  1  1   1   4
5:  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0   1   4
6:  1  1  0  1  1  0  1  0  1   1   4
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 ans
1:  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  1   1   5
2:  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  1   1   4
3:  0  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  1   0   2
4:  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  1  1   1   5
5:  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0   1   4
6:  1  1  0  1  1  0  1  0  1   1   5
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 ans
1:  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  1   1   6
2:  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  1   1   4
3:  0  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  1   0   6
4:  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  1  1   1   5
5:  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0   1   4
6:  1  1  0  1  1  0  1  0  1   1   5
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 ans
1:  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  1   1   6
2:  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  1   1   7
3:  0  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  1   0   7
4:  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  1  1   1   7
5:  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0   1   4
6:  1  1  0  1  1  0  1  0  1   1   7
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 ans
1:  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  1   1   8
2:  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  1   1   8
3:  0  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  1   0   8
4:  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  1  1   1   8
5:  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0   1   4
6:  1  1  0  1  1  0  1  0  1   1   7
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 ans
1:  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  1   1   9
2:  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  1   1   9
3:  0  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  1   0   9
4:  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  1  1   1   9
5:  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0   1   4
6:  1  1  0  1  1  0  1  0  1   1   9
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 ans
1:  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  1   1  10
2:  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  1   1  10
3:  0  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  1   0   9
4:  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  1  1   1  10
5:  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0   1  10
6:  1  1  0  1  1  0  1  0  1   1  10
>
```

Comment: It's very nice your solution to the problem (If it is doing what I think), although it's very different from the one I used. Could you please explain what is this doing ``set(a,which(a[[i]]==1),"foo",i)``? Thanks @Matthew Dowle!

Comment: @Nestorghh Have added edit, hth. See `?set` for an explanation of `set`'s arguments.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation @Matthew Dowle. That's what we thought it was doing. Certainly, it's a different style. On the other hand, we did some experiments with huge data tables and the difference is appreciable. We tried with a 2000000-rows data table and your ``set`` solution is 53 times faster than our ``apply`` approach.

Comment: Besides ``?set``, could you please tell me if there is another reference to read more about the ``set`` function? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the update, glad it's working. If you have further questions that aren't answered by `?set` please let me know so it can be improved. Only other place I can think is search [NEWS](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?view=markup&root=datatable) which is quite verbose with examples (`set` was added in v1.8.0).